# Keycloak authorization: CRUD Authorization Policies, Permissions via API

Tags: api, permissions, crud, keycloak, policy

In Keycloak I see there is a CRUD API to create a resource (and scopes):

[http://${host}:${port}/auth/realms/${realm_name}/authz/protection/resource_set](http://$%7Bhost%7D:$%7Bport%7D/auth/realms/$%7Brealm_name%7D/authz/protection/resource_set)

> ```
> Create resource set description: POST /resource_set
> Read resource set description: GET /resource_set/{_id}
> Update resource set description: PUT /resource_set/{_id}
> Delete resource set description: DELETE /resource_set/{_id}
> ```

But I don't see an API to CRUD Authorization Policies, Permissions.

I tried to create policies via the protection/resource_set endpoint but failed:

POST: "policies":[ {...} ]
=> Unrecognized field "policies"

**Is there a way to CRUD Authorization Policies/Permissions via API?**

(I'm not using a java client - I want to do this with postman)

Any help would be grateful

Answer (score 4):

Ok found something ...

When requesting API endpoints like this you get the access to policies/permissions:

[http://${host}:${port}/auth/admin/realms/${realm_name}/clients/${client_id}/authz/resource-server/policy/user/${policy_id}](http://$%7Bhost%7D:$%7Bport%7D/auth/admin/realms/$%7Brealm_name%7D/clients/$%7Bclient_id%7D/authz/resource-server/policy/user/$%7Bpolicy_id%7D)

But I still can't find something in the official documentation about this ...

Comment: Did you find any docs about CRUD operations for resources, scopes, policies & permissions?

Comment: The one that you mentioned is used by keycloak admin console UI. As you mentioned, there is no official documentation till now. Why? is there any reason? 

Please comment on it if anyone knows about this.

Comment: @SANDEEPMACHIRAJU Apologies for the late reply. I took a look at the [REST Admin](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/8.0/rest-api/index.html#_overview) and it seems that when creating a client, you can send the authorization settings via the request body. The `POST /{realm}clients` for instance takes a `ClientRepresentation` which in turn takes a `ResourceServerRepresentation` which in turn (again) takes policies, resources and scope representations.

Comment: Yes, the POST endpoint uses the given policies and permissions. But when you want to update a client using PUT, Keycloak ignores any given policies and permission -.-